# EFD-Reinf: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor - Identificador: 3033699826

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou tentando enviar um teste do evento R-1000 do Reinf e me retorna:

> O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (500) Erro Interno do Servidor.
>   Falha no processamento. Favor tentar novamente. Identificador: 3033699826

Alguém poderia me ajudar??

Segue o código:

```
string xmlRequisicaoSOAP = MontarXmlRequisicao();

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(this.URL);
        //request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", string.Format("\"{0}{1}\"", XMLNS, METODO));
        request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", @"https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc");
        request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        request.Accept = "text/xml";
        request.Method = "POST";
      //  request.Proxy = proxy;

        if (this.Certificado != null)
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(this.Certificado);
        if (this.TimeOutEmSegundos > 0)
            request.Timeout = this.TimeOutEmSegundos * 1000;

        this.UltimaRequisicao = xmlRequisicaoSOAP;
        try
        {

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    stmw.Write(xmlRequisicaoSOAP);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception wex)
        {
           throw  new Exception(wex.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            WebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webresponse;
            //if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            string mensagemSubjacente = ObterMensagemSubjacente(wex);
            string msg = string.Format("{1}\r\n{0}\r\n Detalhes subjacentes: \r\n{2}",
                System.Environment.NewLine, wex.Message, mensagemSubjacente);
            throw new ExcecaoComunicacaoREINF(msg, wex, xmlRequisicaoSOAP);
            //  throw new Exception(wex.Message); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ExcecaoComunicacaoREINF(ex.Message, ex, xmlRequisicaoSOAP);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Quem é `reinf`?

Comment: Desculpe. estou tentando enviar o arquivo do EFD-Reinf para a receita federal.

Comment: Inclua o código que você desenvolveu para o envio.

Comment: Alguem poderia me ajudar???

Comment: Qual é a descrição de erro do código 3033699826 na documentação do serviço que você está interagindo?

Comment: Na SEFAZ nao encontrei nada.

Comment: Rogerio, eu respondi na sua outra pergunta, que está melhor detalhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269338/86952

Comment: Em minha opinião, todos estes sistemas do governo precisam ter um melhor suporte ao desenvolvedor, mais estabilidade e melhor e mais simplificada documentação e formas de acesso via Web API.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Problema para envio SPED-REINF c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269338/problema-para-envio-sped-reinf-c)