# EFD-Reinf: O que fazer para não dar falha de certificado?

Tags: c#, web-service

Estou trabalhando no envio de informações do EFD-Reinf e estou enfrentando problemas de envio.

Me baseei no código postado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269338/86952) para fazer o envio, entretanto sempre cai no `catch` da `WebException` com a mensagem abaixo:

> The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Entretanto, o certificado que estou utilizando é valido pois ele não está expirado e o cliente usa ele para enviar informações.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

```c#
private string ExecuteTransmission(string filePath)
{
    X509Certificate2 digitalCertificate;
    XmlDocument xmlFile;
    XmlTextWriter xmlWriter;
    HttpWebRequest request;
    string certPath = "AQUI VAI O CAMINHO COMPLETO DO CERTIFICADO";
    string password = "SENHA DO CERTIFICADO";

    xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
    xmlFile.Load(filePath.Trim());
    xmlWriter = new XmlTextWriter(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    xmlWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
    xmlFile.Save(xmlWriter);
    xmlWriter.Close();
    xmlWriter = null;

    request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_urlToSend);
    request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", _urlToSend);
    request.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
    request.Accept = "text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";

    digitalCertificate = ReinfUtil.GetCertificate(certPath, password);

    DigitalcCertificateExtension.CheckValidate(digitalCertificate);

    if (digitalCertificate != null)
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(digitalCertificate);
    // if (this.TimeOutEmSegundos > 0)
    //     request.Timeout = this.TimeOutEmSegundos * 1000;
    try
    {
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (StreamWriter stmw = new StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                stmw.Write(xmlFile.InnerXml);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception wex)
    {
        throw new Exception(wex.Message);
    }

    try
    {
        WebResponse webresponse = request.GetResponse();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webresponse;
        //if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string result = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException wex)
    {
        string subjacentMesssage = ReinfUtil.GetSubjacentMessage(wex);
        string msg = string.Format("{1}\r\n{0}\r\n Detalhes subjacentes: \r\n{2}",
            System.Environment.NewLine, wex.Message, subjacentMesssage);
        throw new BusinessException(msg);
        //  throw new Exception(wex.Message); 
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

---

**EDIÇÃO**

Pelo que vejo essa mensagem acontece porque o próprio endereço da receita está com um certificado inválido. Eu não esperava que isso fosse acontecer. Vou dar mais uma olhada na documentação deles e ver se tem algo a ser feito para superar o problema se não vou tentar ignorar a exceção de segurança para executar a requisição mesmo assim.

Comment: O código que me baseei está disponível em :https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269338/problema-para-envio-sped-reinf-c?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você já identificou parte do problema: O certificado do SERPRO não é reconhecido como um certificado confiável. Veja que mesmo acessando o [endereço do serviço](https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc) pelo navegador você será avisado que o endereço é inseguro e provavelmente aparecerá um cadeado vermelho ao lado do URL.

Para que o certificado do serviço do EFD-Reinf seja considerado confiável, possibilitando que seja acessado também via código, você precisa instalar 3 certificados disponibilizados pelo SERPRO, para completar a cadeia do certificado do serviço.

Os 3 certificados necessários estão disponíveis na seção "**Cadeia de Certificados emitida em 06/02/2017**", no seguinte endereço:

> https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain

Mas, segue abaixo a lista com a ordem de instalação dos certificados, os links diretos de cada um e onde devem ser instalados:

1. [Autoridade Certificadora Raiz Brasileira v5](https://repositorio.serpro.gov.br/docs/icpbrasilv5.crt) -> Deve ser instalado no repositório de AC (Autoridades de Certificação) **Raiz**;
2. [Autoridade Certificadora SERPRO v4](https://repositorio.serpro.gov.br/docs/acserprov4.crt) -> Deve ser instalado no repositório de AC (Autoridades de Certificação) **Intermediárias**;
3. [Autoridade Certificadora do SERPRO Final v5](https://repositorio.serpro.gov.br/docs/acserproacfv5.crt) -> Deve ser instalado no repositório de AC (Autoridades de Certificação) **Intermediárias**.

Eu não sei porquê eles não incluíram essas instruções no [Manual do Desenvolvedor do EFD-Reinf](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/download/2897) (versão 1.04.00), mas no [Manual do Desenvolvedor do eSocial](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/manualorientacaodesenvolvedoresocialv1-7.pdf) (versão 1.7), na seção "**7.9. Certificação digital**", na página 115, eles mencionam esses passos, e na página de Perguntas Frequentes do eSocial há mais alguns detalhes. Vi agora que no Perguntas Frequentes do EFD-Reinf eles também mencionam a necessidade de instalar a cadeia de certificados do SERPRO.

Algumas fontes:

- [Acessando os serviços do eSocial na web (Web Services)](http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AcessandoServicos.htm)
- [Perguntas Frequentes - Produção Empresas e Produção Restrita - eSocial](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/institucional/ambiente-de-producao-empresas/perguntas-frequentes-producao-empresas-e-producao-restrita) (item 02.03)
- [Perguntas Frequentes EFD-Reinf](http://sped.rfb.gov.br/pastaperguntas/show/1497) (item 3.2)

Aproveitando, no seu código você está usando a mesma variável tanto para o endereço do serviço quanto para o `SOAPAction`, mas, você deve usar valores diferentes nesses dois casos.

Para o URL do serviço você deve usar:

> *No ambiente de Produção (oficial):*
>   https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc
>
> *No ambiente de Produção Restrita (teste):*
>   https://preprodefdreinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc

Já no `SOAPAction` você deve usar esse valor (você pode ve-lo definido no [WSDL do serviço](https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc?singleWsdl)):
`"http://sped.fazenda.gov.br/RecepcaoLoteReinf/ReceberLoteEventos"`

E, uma dica, é muito mais fácil [adicionar uma referência ao serviço](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/307466/86952) do EFD-Reinf no projeto, usando o Visual Studio, através do [WSDL do serviço](https://reinf.receita.fazenda.gov.br/WsREINF/RecepcaoLoteReinf.svc?singleWsdl), e usar a classe gerada, que herda `System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`, para que o .NET faça todo o trabalho de comunicação SOAP para você, ao invés de você ter que fazer tudo na mão, usando `HttpWebRequest`.

Se você quiser, aqui há um exemplo de como fazer dessa forma que falei:

- [Como consumir WebService do EFD-Reinf no C#? (Envio Eventos) - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343200/86952)

E aqui há um exemplo do jeito que você está fazendo, usando `HttpWebRequest`, só que para eSocial:

- [Erro 400 ao enviar requisição para o ESocial (C#) - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/329364/86952)

Aliás, aqui no SOpt há várias outras perguntas e respostas sobre [efd-reinf](/questions/tagged/efd-reinf) e [esocial](/questions/tagged/esocial), caso precise de outras respostas.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua reposta detalhada. Vou executar as instruções e postar aqui se deu certo. Quanto ao mapeamento do serviço eu já estava pensando em fazer, só não fiz porque tinha o código aparentemente pronto aqui. Abraço!

Answer (score 0):

Pedro Gaspar, suas indicações foram determinadas para destravar o meu desenvolvimento. Mais uma vez, obrigado!

Na verdade estou desenvolvendo em um projeto que trabalha com dotnet core onde as estações de desenvolvimento são em linux com vscode.
Para fazer isso acontecer tive que encontrar a saída para algumas coisa como, por exemplo, a ferramenta para mapear serviços no dotnet core é o svcutil, entretanto não consegui mpear o serviço do reinf nele, levantei uma vm windows, instalei o visual studio e consegui fazer o mapeamento, depois segui trabalhando no linux e vs code. Segue abaixo a versão inicial do método que funciona em dotnet core.

```
    {
        // Carrega o certificado digital a partir de um arquivo PFX, informando a senha.
        X509Certificate2 x509Cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath, certPassword);
        // Carrega o XML de lote a partir de um arquivo.
        // Mas os XMLs dos eventos devem ser assinados digitalmente antes de inseridos no XML de lote.
        // Para isso é possível usar a função SignXmlDoc() disponível na resposta abaixo:
        // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277476/
        XDocument eventsBlockXDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

        var address = new EndpointAddress(environmentUrl);
        // BasicHttpsBinding está disponível somente a partir do .NET Framework 4.5.
        // Se estiver usando uma versão anterior, use a linha comentada abaixo.
        //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport);
        var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

        // Informa que será usado um certificado digital para acessar o serviço.
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        // Veja essa pergunta para mais detalhes:
        // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/318351/
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        // Cria o objeto cliente (do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase) para acesso ao WebService.
        var wsClient = new RecepcaoLoteReinfClient(binding, address);
        // Passa o certificado digital para o objeto do tipo System.ServiceModel.ClientBase.
        wsClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = x509Cert;

        // Veja: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303859/
        await wsClient.OpenAsync();           


        // Chama o WebService de fato, passando o XML do lote.
        // O método espera um objeto do tipo XElement, e retorna outro objeto XElement.

        var feedbackXElement = await wsClient.ReceberLoteEventosAsync(eventsBlockXDoc.Root);

        await wsClient.CloseAsync();


    }
```

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu resolver o problema @user1927055! Mas, talvez você ainda não esteja familizarizado com o funcionamento aqui do site. Ele serve para resolver dúvidas e problemas individuais, mas, o propósito maior dele é servir como um repositório de soluções para todos os desenvolvedores, com um sistema prático de perguntas e respostas. Então, para a sua pergunta específica, do erro `The SSL connection could not be established` que estava ocorrendo, qual resposta resolveu de fato o problema, a minha ou a sua?

Comment: Marque por favor como resposta a que tiver resolvido esse problema específico, para ficar bem documentado para pessoas que venham procurar essa solução no futuro! E, caso a sua resposta não seja de fato uma resposta ao problema original, você pode editar a pergunta e colocar essa mensagem no final dela, complementando a pergunta. Você pode por exemplo indicar um cabeçalho **Edição**, ou **Complemento**, ou **Solução**, ou qualquer coisa do tipo, indicando que foi algo adicionado depois da solução do problema.

Comment: Não sei se você percebeu mas eu já havia editado a sua pergunta adicionando como **EDIÇÃO** o texto que você tinha postado como resposta, porque não era de fato uma resposta, e sim um complemento da pergunta. Também adicionei à pergunta o link que você tinha postado como comentário.