# Soap Request 403 forbidden

Tags: java, soap, certificado-digital, api, keystore

Olá pessoal por gentileza preciso da ajuda de vocês.

Estou tentando enviar fazer a conexão com a api do esocial mas tenho o retorno 403 forbidden, estou com certificado atualizado 
e utilizando o jks. Segue abaixo o trecho onde carrego o certificado para fazer a requisição com o webServiceTemplate

```
 package br.jus.tjba.esocial.config;  

import java.io.InputStream;  
import java.net.Socket;  
import java.security.*;  
import java.security.cert.Certificate;  
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;  

import javax.crypto.Cipher;  
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;  
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManager;  
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;  
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;  
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;  
import javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager;  

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;  
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.NoopHostnameVerifier;  
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;  
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;  
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;  
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;  
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender;  
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpComponentsMessageSender.RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor;  

import br.jus.tjba.esocial.util.WsUtils;  

/** 
* 
* @author Rafael Vasco, Vinicius Cidreira 
*/  
@Configuration  
public class WsConfig {  

    @Value("${serpro.ssl.key-store}")  
    private Resource resourceKeyStore;  
    @Value("serpro.ssl.privatekey-store")  
    private Resource privateKey;  

    @Value("${serpro.ssl.key-store-password}")  
    private String resourceKeyStorePassword;  

    @Value("${serpro.ssl.private-key}")  
    private String privateKeyStorePassword;  

    @Value("${serpro.ssl.alias}")  
    private String alias;  

    @Value("${serpro.protocol}")  
    private String protocol;  

    @Bean  
    public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {  
        WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();  
        webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(httpComponentsMessageSender());  

        return webServiceTemplate;  
    }  

    public HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender() throws Exception {  
        HttpComponentsMessageSender httpComponentsMessageSender = new HttpComponentsMessageSender();  
        httpComponentsMessageSender.setHttpClient(httpClient());  

        return httpComponentsMessageSender;  
    }  

    public HttpClient httpClient() throws Exception {  
        return HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory())  
                .addInterceptorFirst(new RemoveSoapHeadersInterceptor())  
                .build();  
    }  

    public SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory() throws Exception {  
        // NoopHostnameVerifier essentially turns hostname verification off as otherwise  
        // following error  
        // is thrown: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching  
        // localhost found  
        return new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext(), NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);  
    }  

    public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {  

        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);  

        KeyStore keyStore = WsUtils.loadKeyStore(resourceKeyStore.getInputStream(), resourceKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());  
        PrivateKey privateKey = null;  
        try {  
            privateKey = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey(  
                    alias,  
                    privateKeyStorePassword.toCharArray()  
            );  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.getMessage();  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        InputStream fileCacerts = WsUtils.getCacert();  
        X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) keyStore.getCertificate(alias);  

        final KeyManager[] keyManagers = createKeyManagers(keyStore, alias, certificate, privateKey);  
        final TrustManager[] trustManagers = createTrustManagers(fileCacerts);  
        sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, null);  
        fileCacerts.close();  

        return sslContext;  

    }  

    private KeyManager[] createKeyManagers(KeyStore keyStore, String alias, X509Certificate certificate, PrivateKey privateKey) {  
        return new KeyManager[]{new NFKeyManager(keyStore, alias, certificate, privateKey)};  
    }  

    private TrustManager[] createTrustManagers(InputStream fileCacerts) throws Exception {  
        final TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());  
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");  
        trustStore.load(fileCacerts, resourceKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());  
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);  
        return trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();  
    }  


    class NFKeyManager implements X509KeyManager {  

        private final X509Certificate certificate;  
        private final PrivateKey privateKey;  
        private KeyStore keyStore;  
        private String alias;  

        NFKeyManager(KeyStore keyStore, String alias, final X509Certificate certificate, final PrivateKey privateKey) {  
            this.certificate = certificate;  
            this.privateKey = privateKey;  
            this.keyStore = keyStore;  
            this.alias = alias;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public String chooseClientAlias(final String[] arg0, final Principal[] arg1, final Socket arg2) {  
            return this.certificate.getIssuerDN().getName();  
        }  

        @Override  
        public String chooseServerAlias(final String arg0, final Principal[] arg1, final Socket arg2) {  
            return null;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public X509Certificate[] getCertificateChain(final String arg0) {  
            try {  
                Certificate[] certificates = keyStore.getCertificateChain(alias);  
                X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = new X509Certificate[certificates.length];  
                System.arraycopy(certificates, 0, x509Certificates, 0, certificates.length);  
                return x509Certificates;  
            } catch (KeyStoreException e) {  
                return new X509Certificate[]{this.certificate};  
            }  
        }  

        @Override  
        public String[] getClientAliases(final String arg0, final Principal[] arg1) {  
            return new String[]{this.certificate.getIssuerDN().getName()};  
        }  

        @Override  
        public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(final String arg0) {  
            return this.privateKey;  
        }  

        @Override  
        public String[] getServerAliases(final String arg0, final Principal[] arg1) {  
            return null;  
        }  
    }  

}
```

aqui o xml gerado para envio

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:v1="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">  
   <soap:Body>  
      <v1:EnviarLoteEventos>  
         <v1:loteEventos>  
            <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">  
               <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">  
                  <ideEmpregador>  
                     <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>  
                     <nrInsc>13100760</nrInsc>  
                  </ideEmpregador>  
                  <ideTransmissor>  
                     <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>  
                     <nrInsc>131007221111444</nrInsc>  
                  </ideTransmissor>  
                  <eventos>  
                     <evento Id="ID1131007220000002019081317143000001">  
                        <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_02">  
                           <idEvento>ID11310072200888888888081317143555555</idEvento>  
                           <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1131007220000002019081317143000001">  
                              <ideEmpregador>  
                                 <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>  
                                 <nrInsc>13100722</nrInsc>  
                              </ideEmpregador>  
                              <infoEmpregador>  
                                 <inclusao>  
                                    <idePeriodo>  
                                       <iniValid>2019-07</iniValid>  
                                    </idePeriodo>  
                                    <infoCadastro>  
                                       <nmRazao>TJBAA</nmRazao>  
                                       <classTrib>85</classTrib>  
                                       <natJurid>1082</natJurid>  
                                       <indCoop>0</indCoop>  
                                       <indConstr>0</indConstr>  
                                       <indDesFolha>0</indDesFolha>  
                                       <indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron>  
                                       <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>  
                                       <indEtt>N</indEtt>  
                                       <contato>  
                                          <nmCtt>TESTE PIMENTA</nmCtt>  
                                          <cpfCtt>78177766520</cpfCtt>  
                                          <foneFixo>7133721896</foneFixo>  
                                          <foneCel>71988925970</foneCel>  
                                       </contato>  
                                       <infoOP>  
                                          <indUGRPPS>N</indUGRPPS>  
                                          <esferaOP>2</esferaOP>  
                                          <poderOP>2</poderOP>  
                                          <vrTetoRem>33763</vrTetoRem>  
                                          <ideEFR>N</ideEFR>  
                                          <cnpjEFR>13937032000160</cnpjEFR>  
                                       </infoOP>  
                                       <infoOrgInternacional>  
                                          <indAcordoIsenMulta>0</indAcordoIsenMulta>  
                                       </infoOrgInternacional>  
                                       <softwareHouse>  
                                          <cnpjSoftHouse>13100722</cnpjSoftHouse>  
                                          <nmRazao>TESTE TESTE</nmRazao>  
                                          <nmCont>LEANDRO SADY RODRIGUES</nmCont>  
                                          <telefone>71999999999</telefone>  
                                          <email>lgues@teste.br</email>  
                                       </softwareHouse>  
                                       <infoComplementares>  
                                          <situacaoPJ>  
                                             <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>  
                                          </situacaoPJ>  
                                       </infoComplementares>  
                                    </infoCadastro>  
                                 </inclusao>  
                              </infoEmpregador>  
                           </evtInfoEmpregador>  
                           <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">  
                              <SignedInfo>  
                                 <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />  
                                 <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />  
                                 <Reference URI="">  
                                    <Transforms>  
                                       <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />  
                                       <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />  
                                    </Transforms>  
                                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />  
                                    <DigestValue>[...]</DigestValue>  
                                 </Reference>  
                              </SignedInfo>  
                              <SignatureValue>[...]</SignatureValue>  
                              <KeyInfo>  
                                 <X509Data>  
                                    <X509Certificate>[...]</X509Certificate>  
                                 </X509Data>  
                              </KeyInfo>  
                           </Signature>  
                        </eSocial>  
                     </evento>  
                  </eventos>  
               </envioLoteEventos>  
            </eSocial>  
         </v1:loteEventos>  
      </v1:EnviarLoteEventos>  
   </soap:Body>  
</soap:Envelope>
```

Aqui o trecho onde faço o envio do xml acima

```
RetornoEnvio response = (RetornoEnvio) webServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(settings.getUrlEnviarlotes(),  
                soapActionCallback, new WebServiceMessageExtractor<Object>() {  
                    public Object extractData(WebServiceMessage response) throws IOException {  
                        Assert.isInstanceOf(SoapMessage.class, response);  
                        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) response;  

                        try {  

                            final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();  

                            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()  
                                    .transform(new DOMSource(soapMessage.getDocument()), new StreamResult(sw));  

                            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RetornoEnvio.class);  

                            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();  

                            XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()  
                                    .createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(  
                                            XMLUtils.extractValueByTag(sw.toString(), "EnviarLoteEventosResult")));  

                            XMLReaderWithoutNamespace readerWithoutNamespace = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(  
                                    xmlStreamReader);  

                            RetornoEnvio retorno = (RetornoEnvio) unmarshaller.unmarshal(readerWithoutNamespace);  
                            retorno.setXmlEnvio(xmlEnvio);  
                            return retorno;  

                        } catch (Exception e) {  
                            throw new IOException("Error in unmarshaller xml return.", e);  
                        }  
                    }  
                });
```

Não sei onde estou errando, caso precisar de mais detalhes só falar já tentei quase tudo e sempre retornar o mesmo erro 
Consigo acessar a url pelo browser e o evento que estou tentando enviar é o S1000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue um exemplo simples de conexão/consumo de um ws no java com certificado.

```java
package ws_client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class Consumindo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String url_ws = "https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx?op=nfeDistDFeInteresse";
        String path_pk = "/path/to/file.pfx";
        String pass = "pk_pass";
        String soap_message = "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><soap12:Header><nfeCabecMsg xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe\"><versaoDados>1.00</versaoDados></nfeCabecMsg></soap12:Header><soap12:Body><nfeDistDFeInteresse xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe\"><nfeDadosMsg><distDFeInt versao=\"1.00\" xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\"><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor><CNPJ>00000000000000</CNPJ><distNSU><ultNSU>000000000000001</ultNSU></distNSU></distDFeInt></nfeDadosMsg></nfeDistDFeInteresse></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>";
        Consumindo c  = new Consumindo();
        System.out.println(c.consome(url_ws, path_pk, pass, soap_message));

    }
    public String consome(String url_ws, String path_pk, String pass, String soap_message) throws Exception{


        // Aqui vc carrega sua chave privada
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(path_pk));
        ks.load(fis, pass.toCharArray());
        fis.close();

        URL url = new URL(url_ws);

        // Com isso não será checado de o certificado do site é válido ou não
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { 
            new X509TrustManager() {
                @Override
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                @Override
                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                @Override
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null;}
            }
        };

        // Aqui vc cria o gerenciador de chave que vai ser chamado mais a baixo
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        kmf.init(ks, pass.toCharArray());

        // Cria-se o contexto da requisição, onde vc vai ignorar qualquer erro do certificado da URL (CA não reconhecida pelo java por exemplo)
        // e também adiciona a chave privada no contexto, necesária para consumir o ws
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

        // define que vc vai usar o contexto em HttpsURLConnection 
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());

        HttpsURLConnection uc = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // define que vai enviar dados da requisição
        uc.setDoOutput(true);
        uc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
        OutputStream wr = uc.getOutputStream();
        wr.write(soap_message.getBytes());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();



        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();
        return response.toString();
    }
}
```

Para consumir o WS em

https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc

Precisa definir a url como:

```
String url_ws = "https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc";
```

E precisa definir um novo atributo no header do request

```
uc.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "http://www.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_0/ServicoEnviarLoteEventos/EnviarLoteEventos");
```

Comment: Qual a url do WS?

Comment: https://webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br/servicos/empregador/enviarloteeventos/WsEnviarLoteEventos.svc

Answer (score 1):

A comunicação com os serviços do eSocial deve ser feita através do protocolo de comunicação [HTTPS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper_Text_Transfer_Protocol_Secure), usando o protocolo de criptografia [TLS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security), e, citando o [Manual do Desenvolvedor do eSocial](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/manualorientacaodesenvolvedoresocialv1-7.pdf/view), na página 19:

> *O meio físico de comunicação utilizado será a Internet, com o uso do protocolo
>   HTTPS (TLS), com **autenticação mútua**, que além de garantir um duto de comunicação seguro na Internet, permite a **identificação do servidor e do cliente** através de **certificados digitais**.*

O que significa que é necessário informar um certificado digital válido do lado cliente para estabelecer a conexão com o serviço, mas que também existe uma verificação do certificado do servidor. O código de resposta HTTP [**403 Forbidden**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) (*Proibido*) normalmente indica que houve algum tipo de falha com os certificados, ao acessar o serviço.

Eu programo principalmente usando o .NET Framework e não entendo muito de Java, mas, pelo que pude entender do seu código me parece que o certificado digital já está sendo informado no contexto da conexão com o serviço. Mas além disso é necessário checar:

- O certificado digital usado para a conexão está dentro da validade?
- Ele é um certificado e-CNPJ ou e-CPF da série A (A1 ou A3)?

Entretanto, é provável que o problema esteja no **certificado do servidor**, já que o certificado do SERPRO não é reconhecido como um certificado confiável, e por isso é necessário instalar no computador cliente uma cadeia de certificados fornecida por eles (os 3 certificados abaixo do item "**Cadeia de Certificados emitida em 06/02/2017**", [nesta página](https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain)). Veja mais detalhes sobre isso nessa resposta:

- [EFD-Reinf: O que fazer para não dar falha de certificado?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/361421/86952)

Veja também o item 02.01 da página de [Perguntas Frequentes](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/institucional/ambiente-de-producao-empresas/perguntas-frequentes-producao-empresas-e-producao-restrita) do eSocial:

> ***02.01 - (11/01/2018) Apesar de instalados todos os certificados requeridos, o eSocial retorna a mensagem de erro 403. Gostaria de informações de como acessar o ambiente de produção.***
>   *As orientações sobre utilização de certificação digital constam na seção "4.4. Padrão de certificado digital" do Manual de Orientação do Desenvolvedor, disponível na área de  [Documentação Técnica](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/institucional/documentacao-tecnica). Além disso, vale lembrar que os certificados utilizados devem estar no prazo de validade. O usuário deverá instalar em seus servidores a cadeia de certificado do eSocial que está disponível em: https://certificados.serpro.gov.br/serproacf/certificate-chain.*

Answer (score 0):

Segue o a alteração:

```
public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {


    KeyStore keyStore = WsUtils.loadKeyStore(resourceKeyStore.getInputStream(), resourceKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    kmf.init(keyStore, resourceKeyStorePassword.toCharArray());
    KeyManager[] kms = kmf.getKeyManagers();

    InputStream fileCacerts = WsUtils.getCacert();
    final TrustManager[] trustManagers = createTrustManagers(fileCacerts);

    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance(protocol);
    sslContext.init(kms, trustManagers,new SecureRandom());
    fileCacerts.close();
    return sslContext;



}

public static InputStream getCacert() throws Exception {

        char[] senha = "changeit".toCharArray();

        Path cacertPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "lib", "security", "cacerts");
        Path savePath = Paths.get(CAMINHO_TEMP, "cacerts");

        File arquivoCacert = new File(cacertPath.toString());

        if (!arquivoCacert.isFile()) {

            throw new Exception("Arquivo cacerts não encontrado no JRE");
        }

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(arquivoCacert);

        // Obtem KeyStore do Java
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, senha);
        in.close();

        // Adiciona caminhos das URLs ESOCIAL ao KeyStore
        get("webservices.producaorestrita.esocial.gov.br", ks);

        // Salva
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(savePath.toString());
        ks.store(out, senha);
        out.close();

        InputStream retorno = new FileInputStream(savePath.toString());

        return retorno;
    }
```

Um tópico também que me ajudou na implementação:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994944/connect-to-a-https-site-with-a-given-p12-certificate

Obrigado a todos que ajudaram.